# c Curl get request to variable

Tags: c++, curl, get

Sure I am missing something obvious, but trying to make a curl get request and return the response to a variable.

```
size_t write_to_string(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, std::string stream){
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
    std::string temp(static_cast<const char*>(ptr), realsize);

    cout << temp << endl;

    return realsize;
}    

CURLcode curl_get(const std::string& url, std::ostream& os, long timeout = 30){
    CURLcode code(CURLE_FAILED_INIT);
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();

    string *response;

    if (curl){

        if (CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &write_to_string))
            && CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L))
            && CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L))
            && CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FILE, &os))
            && CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, response))
            && CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, timeout))
            && CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str())))
        {
            code = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        }
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    std::string a = *response;

    return code;
```

}

response is always either null or an out of bounds pointer from the dozen ways I have tried. The cout does show the correct response. 
All I am trying to do is create a generic function for all curl get calls and have it return the get data. New to c, so sorry if I am overlooking something simple.

Comment: your tagging this as 'c' however the code references `std::strings&` and similar, which does not exist in C.  please remove the 'c' tag and add the 'c++' tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You declare `write_to_string` to accept `std::string` but you pass it a pointer to `std::string` (via `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA`).
2. You don't do anything with `std::string stream` in `write_to_string`.
3. You declare `response` as a `std::string*` but do not initialize it, so you have dangling pointer.